# Sugar CRM shows variable and not value in email

Tags: php, sugarcrm

Everytime I try to reset a password, it sends me a email with the variable showing and instead of the value. I checked permissions and they seem to be fine. below is a sample of what it looks like

```
You recently requested on 2011-06-13 15:03:40 to be able to reset your account password. 
Click on the link below to reset your password:
$contact_user_link_guid //This should be a link not a variable
```

I also checked the server logs for any glaring issues, but seems to be fine as well. This a fairly new install.

I check this issue out in google. others had the same problem but no solution was given.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of SugarCRM are you on? I'm not able to reproduce on Sugar 6.2, and the only bug we ever received on this issue indicated it was a configuration issue with selecting the wrong email template for the 'Reset Password' e-mail.

Comment: I am using Version 6.1.4 (Build 5822)

Answer (score 0):

My CRM is under SugarCRM 6.5.15

I had exactly the same problem.
I fixed it like jmertic said, in admin panel, the wrong template was selected. I just changed to the right template and now the auto-generated password works.